# Image find Red eye removal android

Tags: android

I want to remove red eye effect form photo but not get any sample can any one help me with working demo code in android or code snippet?

Thanks.

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself."

Comment: any tutorial have image detected  red eye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android eye detection and tracking with OpenCV](http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/)

This tutorial will help to detect eye

Comment: how to detect image not camera